# boost asio arduino error: boost::wrapexcept<boost::system::system_error>

Tags: winapi, boost, arduino, boost-asio

I have the following line of code is giving me an error:

```
boost::asio::serial_port serial(ioservice, "COM3");
```

The errors are:

> Exception thrown at 0x7602A8B2 in WindowsProject2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::wrapexceptboost::system::system_error at memory location 0x010FE4A8.
> Unhandled exception at 0x7602A8B2 in WindowsProject2.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: boost::wrapexceptboost::system::system_error at memory location 0x010FE4A8.

I am trying to connnect to an arduino through COM3 port. I am using windows 32 desktop app.  The code works for windows 32 console app. So it is a win32 desktop app error im guessing it doesn't like "COM3"? I also tried changing to unicode, multi byte set, and not set and still didnt work.

Comment: There is no difference between a Windows desktop application and a console application, with the exception that the system will allocate a console for a console application on launch. To figure out the root cause, wrap the call inside a C++ exception handler to get at the error code.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, wrong serial of no permissions. It would be easy to find out by reading the error

```
try {
    boost::asio::serial_port serial(ioservice, "COM3");
} catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
    std::cout << "Error " << se.code().message() << "\n";
}
```